# Django tutorial. Generic views. context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

Tags: django, generics, view

I'm a bit confused with Django generic views. As shown in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/#amend-views) we are converting custom views into generic views. And while I understand what happens in DetailView and ResultsView, I don't entirely grasp how this:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

converts into this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

1. In the first example, `latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]`
2. But in the second example, what `latest_question_list` variable is equal to in here? We haven't even defined it..

Can anyone please shed some light into this?

Comment: Ok, I got it. For the future reference. In our index.html template we have used: ```{% for question in latest_question_list %}``` <-- so that's why we want to avoid using the default ``question_list`` automatically generated by Django, and specify our own which is ``latest_question_list``

Comment: [Here's a YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3yB0_4Yd48) on Django generics which clears this up. Even without the context of this video's project, the project set up is small and extremely similar to the official Django 3 tutorials. I found it more useful than the accepted answer, if not at least supporting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [**`ListView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) behind the curtains performs a lot of operations to create a context and pass that to a render engine. We can take a look at the implementation through [*Classy Class-Based Views*](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/).

In essence when you trigger such class-based view you will, depending on the HTTP method, trigger the `get(..)`, `post(..)`, etc. method.

The `get(..)` method is defined by the `BaseListView` class, and defined as:

> ```
> def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
>     allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()
>     if not allow_empty:
>         # When pagination is enabled and object_list is a queryset,
>         # it's better to do a cheap query than to load the unpaginated
>         # queryset in memory.
>         if self.get_paginate_by(self.object_list) is not None and hasattr(self.object_list, 'exists'):
>             is_empty = not self.object_list.exists()
>         else:
>             is_empty = not self.object_list
>         if is_empty:
>             raise Http404(_("Empty list and '%(class_name)s.allow_empty' is False.") % {
>                 'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
>             })
>     context = self.get_context_data()
>     return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

The import part is that we first the result of `get_queryset()` to `self.objects_list`, and later construct a context with `self.get_context_data()`. We then make a call to `self.render_to_response(..)` which basically will use the specified template, and render it with the given `context`.

The `get_context` data has two parents with an implementation. The most basic (highest in the inheritance hierarchy) is that of the `ContextMixin`, but this function does not do much:

> ```
> def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
>     kwargs.setdefault('view', self)
>     if self.extra_context is not None:
>         kwargs.update(self.extra_context)
>     return kwargs
> ```

It simply takes the dictionary constructed by the keyword arguments (empty if there are no keyword arguments, which is the case here), and it adds an extra key `'view'` that is associated with `self`. It also can add extra key-value pairs that can be defined in `self.extra_context`, but we can ignore that here.

The most interesting logic is implemented in the `MultipleObjectMixin`:

> ```
> def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
>     """Get the context for this view."""
>     queryset = object_list if object_list is not None else self.object_list
>     page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
>     context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
>     if page_size:
>         paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
>         context = {
>             'paginator': paginator,
>             'page_obj': page,
>             'is_paginated': is_paginated,
>             'object_list': queryset
>         }
>     else:
>         context = {
>             'paginator': None,
>             'page_obj': None,
>             'is_paginated': False,
>             'object_list': queryset
>         }
>     if context_object_name is not None:
>         context[context_object_name] = queryset
>     context.update(kwargs)
>     return super().get_context_data(**context)
> ```

What happens here is that we first assign `self.object_list`, the variable that we first have set with the outcome of `self.get_queryset` to a local variable named `queryset`. We then will paginate that `queryset`, but that is not very relevant for your question.

We then obtain the name by calling `self.get_context_object_name(queryset)`. By default this is implemented as:

> ```
> def get_context_object_name(self, object_list):
>     """Get the name of the item to be used in the context."""
>     if self.context_object_name:
>         return self.context_object_name
>     elif hasattr(object_list, 'model'):
>         return '%s_list' % object_list.model._meta.model_name
>     else:
>         return None
> ```

So if you have set the `context_object_name` attribute, like you did, then it will simply return that name. So we can conclude that in the `get_context_data(..)`, method, the `context_object_name` will have the name you privided, here `'latest_question_list'`.

We then keep processing the code in `get_context_data(..)`: we construct a dictionary, and at the bottom we check if `context_object_name` is not `None`. If that is the case, we associate the `queryset` with that key (so here with `'latest_question_list'`). Eventually when the correct context dictionary is constructed, we make a `super()` call with the constructed context as `**kwargs`, and as we discussed before, the `ContextMixin`, will simply return that dictionary with very small changes.

So at the end the `context` will have the name of your list (here `'latest_question_list'`) associated with the `queryset`, and it will render the template with that context data.

Answer (score 1):

In class based view you used `context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'`
That why it's similar to `latest_question_list`, you used in function based view.

In class based view, if you don't add `context_object_name` then it's value automatically `object_list`.
Something like `context_object_name='object_list'`.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR version of the accepted answer.

Under the hood, Django does a lot of things in the ListView generic view.

For such a view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
      model=Question
```

The automatically generated context variable is question_list. 
If you want to override it, you must use `context_object_name` variable to set a name for your custom context variable. That's all it is, just setting a name.

Then you must use the `get_queryset` predefined function, which will relate its output to the `context_object_name` variable.

Thus, it is important to use these particular names for the variable and the function.